# I can't connect my custom jquery to wp admin

Tags: custom-post-types, jquery, metabox

I am trying to figure out how to link a custom jquery to my custom meta box created in wordpress custom post type but I can't find it working.

What I want to do is add a line of text when the button is clicked. But it is only reload the "add new post" page and generating a message "Post updated." after I clicked the button.

Here is my code:

**File: doubleit.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("p").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
  });

  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("ol").append("<li>Appended item</li>");
  });
});
```

**Register and Enqueue Script**

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_mytweetjs' );

function add_mytweetjs() {

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js');

    wp_register_script( 'myjquerydoubler', plugins_url( '/js/doubleit.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'myjquerydoubler' );
}
```

**HTML Script On The Custom Meta Box**

```
echo '<p>This is a paragraph.</p>';
echo '<p>This is another paragraph.</p>';
echo '<ol>';
echo '<li>List item 1</li>';
echo '<li>List item 2</li>';
echo '<li>List item 3</li>';
echo '</ol>';
echo '<button id="btn1">Append text</button>';
echo '<button id="btn2">Append list items</button>';
```

May be somebody know where is the fault of my code above.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

## Because YOU CAN'T DEREGISTER JQUERY IN THE ADMIN

#### Why would you even want to?

See src: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php?order=name#L105

```
// Do not allow accidental or negligent deregistering of critical scripts in the admin. Show minimal remorse if the correct hook is used.
if ( is_admin() && 'admin_enqueue_scripts' !== current_filter() ) {
    $no = array(
        'jquery', 'jquery-core', 'jquery-migrate', 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-accordion',
        'jquery-ui-autocomplete', 'jquery-ui-button', 'jquery-ui-datepicker', 'jquery-ui-dialog',
        'jquery-ui-draggable', 'jquery-ui-droppable', 'jquery-ui-menu', 'jquery-ui-mouse',
        'jquery-ui-position', 'jquery-ui-progressbar', 'jquery-ui-resizable', 'jquery-ui-selectable',
        'jquery-ui-slider', 'jquery-ui-sortable', 'jquery-ui-spinner', 'jquery-ui-tabs',
        'jquery-ui-tooltip', 'jquery-ui-widget',
        'underscore', 'backbone',
    );

    if ( in_array( $handle, $no ) ) {
        $message = sprintf( __( 'Do not deregister the %1$s script in the administration area. To target the frontend theme, use the %2$s hook.' ),
            "<code>$handle</code>", '<code>wp_enqueue_scripts</code>' );
        _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, $message, '3.6' );
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi.. thank you! It works now! The only problem I get now is it is reload the page each time I click one of the buttons in the meta box.

Comment: You need to use the event object on the click listener and call preventDefault().  `jQuery("#some_div").click(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); //your code });`

Comment: Awesome. It is perfect now! Thank you very much Chris.O :)